# Get the list of recently executed DML commands

Tags: sql-server

The DBMS is SQL Server 2012 Express. I need to get the list of lost (unsaved) SQL queries which were executed before my hardware system got overheated and rebooted.

Execution of the following script shows some SQL statements, which were not executed by me at all..

```
SELECT 
    SQLTEXT.text, STATS.last_execution_time
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats STATS
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(STATS.sql_handle) AS SQLTEXT
WHERE 
    STATS.last_execution_time > GETDATE()-1
ORDER BY      
    STATS.last_execution_time DESC
```

I know I've done several `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s, but I'm still unable to find them..

Please help.

Comment: Every time the server restarts (whether intentionally or due to your rig blowing up) those dynamic views are cleared. So you wont be able to recover them that way.

Comment: That's weird...

Comment: Just how they work unfortunately